# Edge Animate page working only on Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery-animate, microsoft-edge

I've a problem with my first website that I'm animating through Edge Animate.
My problem is that the animation , with Chrome,IE and android browsers, stops after some seconds and don't proceed to the next steps.
You can see it here:

http://www.crossovertc.it/alpha

I've also trimmed the images to prevent browsers to have a lot of load.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Trim it down to the smallest reproducible case, preferably via a code snippet or jsfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, wich code?

Comment: The code you are having issues with :)